# Internal memory organization of Samsung NAND flash K9WAG08U1D

Tags: memory, nand-flash

I am using samsung K9WAG08U1D NAND flash memory for storing logged data. Datasheet of K9WAG08U1D is shared for part numbers

1. K9F4G08U0D
2. K9K8G08U1D
3. K9K8G08U0D

I am trying to find difference between these multiple chip variants.

Comment: Have you read the datasheet? Its all in there.

Answer (score 2):

For the uninitiated : Data sheet hunting

First place to look is usually near the end where they will have a complete breakdown of order codes by part, unfortunately not the case with samsung so we will trudge on

### Clue 1:

[image]

### Clue 2

[image]

### Clue 3

[image]

### Clue 4

[image]

Combining these clues tells us

- K9F4G08U0D - 4Gb variant, pinout variant 0
- K9K8G08U0D - 8Gb variant, pinout variant 0
- K9K8G08U1D - 8Gb variant, pinout variant 1
- K9WAG08U1D - 16Gb variant, pinout variant 1

So, this flash comes in 4Gb, 8Gb, and 16Gb versions. There are two package variants of the 8Gb model in order to be downward pin compatible with 4Gb version (variant 0) or upward pin compatible with 16Gb version (variant 1)